# ¿Como obtener un width fijo para una imagen en Positioned?

Tags: flutter

estoy tratando de realizar un diseño como este, pero quiero añadirle un width en una imagen que esta en un Container pero no responde, estoy usando stack para primerao tener el container de color purpura y encima la img y un contenido.
En el codigo se puede ver parte del inicio del diseño.
Si hubiera otra forma de hacer ese me ayudaria bastante.
Tambien tenia la duda de que si un Positioned podria tener como child un Row o column para poder tambien trabajarlo asi.

Soy nuevo en flutter.
Alguien me puede ayudar.
Gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:potatoes_test/app_constants/color.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 300,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        )),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Welcome back!',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  imagem(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget imagem() {
    return Positioned(
      left: 100,
      right: 0,
      top: 100,
      bottom: 0,
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          color: Colors.red,
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1), BlendMode.srcOver),
            image: NetworkImage(
                'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRrG4EXV-tktmJoAhbdaOhnQorH_2vQQspj19tt6IYLpdthQfPZY71cCg0jzcU&s',
                scale: 1),
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('231'),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Text('431')
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget texto() {
    return Positioned(
        left: 220,
        right: 0,
        top: 100,
        bottom: 0,
        child: Text('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En el `Positioned` que tiene la imagen, estás poniéndole `left` y `right`, por eso ignora los valores del `Container`.

```dart
Positioned(
      left: 100,
      right: 0,
      top: 100,
      bottom: 0,
```

Solo quítale el `right: 0`, para que haga caso al `width` del `Container`.

Revisa mi canal para Flutter avanzado : [www.youtube.com/diegoveloper](http://www.youtube.com/diegoveloper)